# How to print the highest element of each string prefix within an sorted array in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array consisting of elements with name and date parts (ex: abc20140830).

```
@array = qw/abc20141231 abc20141230 abc20121229 def20141203 def20141202 ghi20141230 ghi20141229 ghi20141228/;
```

I've already sorted this array so that the date part of the string is in descending order. How can i print elements with the latest date of each name prefix i.e., (abc20141231, def20141203, ghi20141230) as the output? These are file names that i eventually have to download

Answer (score 2):

Just keep track of which prefixes you've already seen and skip if you have:

```
my @array = qw/abc20141231 abc20141230 abc20121229 def20141203
            def20141202 ghi20141230 ghi20141229 ghi20141228/;
my %seen;
my @latest = grep !$seen{substr $_, 0, 3}++, @array;
print "$_\n" for @latest;
```

output:

```
abc20141231
def20141203
ghi20141230
```

Comment: Ysth's solution gives me the latest dates for each month. How do i get the overall latest date for each prefix? Ex: from the array abc20141230, abc20141101, abc20141030, abc20141001 it should print abc20141230. Sorry I'm new to perl.

Comment: it works for me; could you show some actual data? I'm finding the prefix as everything but the last eight characters; what do you consider a prefix?

Comment: changed it to use the first 3 characters as prefix

Answer (score 1):

This works. Since the array is already sorted per date, I've grep only the first 3 characters to match. If anyone has a more elegant solution, please post. Thanks.

```
my @array = qw/abc20141231 abc20141230 abc20121229 def20141203
              def20141202 ghi20141230 ghi20141229 ghi20141228/;
my %seen;
my @latest = grep /(.{3})/ && !$seen{$1}++, @array;
```

Comment: Hi, I think you can accept your own answer if it is your preferred approach: even if @ysth helped you ;-) (but vote him up). Since the files are being downloaded (i.e are remote), relying on the file naming scheme to give you the most recent file is the simplest approach; however modules like [Net::SFTP](http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP) and [Net::FTP](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html) do have stat like methods you can use to check if the remote file is newer than a local copy, *etc.*

Answer (score 0):

Since your array is already reverse sorted for date, the first file with a given name in the array is the most recent. To ensure the correct order you could `split` the strings in `@array` and `sort` on the relevant part and then separate the array into lists of files with the same names (other than dates string portion).

The following code does a reverse `sort` (`$b <=> $a`) of the file name strings by the numeric order of the last eight characters (which we grab with `substr($_, -8)`) and `map`s the result into an anonymous array that we pass to `sort`; it then maps the full string from the anonymous array (`$_->[2]`) into the hash reference (`name`) with a key made up of the first three  characters.

I have added a few more entries to the array and used [`Data::Printer`](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) to display the resulting data structure:

```
#!perl
use v5.16;  # adds strict, warnings
my @array = qw/
  abc20141231 abc20141230 abc20121229 def20141203
  def20141202 ghi20141230 ghi20141229 def20140702
  def20141102 ghi20141031 ghi20141227 ghi20131227
  /;
my ($name, $filedate);

map { push @{ $name->{ $_->[1] } } , $_->[2] } 
sort { $b->[0] <=> $a->[0] } 
map {[substr($_, -8), substr($_,0,3), $_]} @array;

for $filedate (sort keys %$name){
  print @{ $name->{$filedate}}[0]."\n" ;
}

END {
use Data::Printer;
p $name ; 
}
```

**output:**

```
abc20141231
def20141203
ghi20141230
{
    abc   [
        [0] "abc20141231",
        [1] "abc20141230",
        [2] "abc20121229"
    ],
    def   [
        [0] "def20141203",
        [1] "def20141202",
        [2] "def20141102",
        [3] "def20140702"
    ],
    ghi   [
        [0] "ghi20141230",
        [1] "ghi20141229",
        [2] "ghi20141227",
        [3] "ghi20141031",
        [4] "ghi20131227"
    ]
}
```

Since your `@array` is already sorted a simpler approach is possible. Your question does assume that the file name "prefix" (the `abc_` part) will be unique so I have assumed that as well.

Comment: Actually my approach is more of a "Schwartzian Transform" sort and looks a bit fancy for something that might be really simple  - simply sorting in place and reassigning to the array might work. As it stands it could be made a bit clearer by naming the array `%_`. Cheers.